# Referencing boolean in interface

Tags: java

I ran into a bit of an issue and was hoping someone could tell me what I'm missing here. 
for some context I have the following methods:

```
private boolean windowork;

    public class WinidowMalfunction extends Event {
        ControllerException newException = new ControllerException("Error:");
        public WinidowMalfunction(long delayTime) {
            super(delayTime);
        }

        public void action() throws ControllerException {
            windowork = false;
            someThingWentWrongHere(1, "Error at WinidowMalfunction");
        }
    }

    private boolean poweron;

    public class PowerOut extends Event {
        public PowerOut(long delayTime) {
            super(delayTime);
        }

        public void action() throws ControllerException {
            poweron = false;
            someThingWentWrongHere(2, "Error at powerOut event");
        }
    }
```

and I'm creating `interface Fixable` where I need to change the value of `poweron` and `windowork` to change their values to `true`. but I can't get the FIxable to accept the references. they are all in the same class so is there a way to reference these boolean function in an interface

---

EDIT:
Assignment question:
In this part, we add functionality for restoring the saved GreenhouseControls object and having it resume execution where it left off. It demonstrates the use of interfaces and the capability of Java methods to return objects.

1. Create the following interface

interface Fixable {

// turns Power on, fix window and zeros out error codes

void fix ();

// logs to a text file in the current directory called fix.log

// prints to the console, and identify time and nature of

// the fix

void log();

}

Comment: What is the compile error you are getting?

Comment: @Thilo I'm not getting a compiling error I'm just getting an error from the IDE saying that that poweron is not declared.

Comment: I'm not certain I understand.  What references are you trying to get?  You can't get references of primitives and even if they were wrapper classes they would be immutable.

Comment: *"I'm creating interface Fixable"* Where? Not in the code you're shown.

Comment: @Andreas I'm creating the interface method bellow the code I have shown it's a ~300 line code so I didn't want to post everything just the part that was relevant

Comment: Then scale it down so you can post it: [How to create a Minimal, Reproducible Example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example)

Answer (score 1):

You can do something like this:

```
interface Fixable {
     public boolean setTrue();
}

class Foo implements Fixable {
    private boolean windowork = false;
    public void setTrue() {
        windowork = true;
    }
}
class Bar implements Fixable {

    private boolean poweron = false;
    public void setTrue() {
        poweron = true;
    }
}
```

The only advantage of the above is if you had an array of `Fixable` objects you could iterate thru them and do this.

```
for (Fixable f : fixableArray) {
   f.setTrue();
}
```

Comment: The idea you mention would probably work but this part of an assignment and they require us to do it in a certain format (I added that to my post at the end)

Comment: You can change the names and tasks of the method(s) of the interface.  This is basically a skeleton for demonstration.

Comment: And just so you are aware, interface methods are implicitly `abstract` and `public`

Comment: oh ok and when I add the log file thing in the second part of `Fixable` it won't interfere with `setTrue` right?

Comment: No they are separate methods.  But they both must be implemented.  That does not mean they both must be called the same number of times, in any order,etc.  You call them when you need to.  Just like in @kiwicptn's example.

Answer (score 0):

An interface can be designed in a way to read-write a boolean property that resides in the class/instance.

```
public interface Somename {

    public boolean isPowerOn();

    public void setPowerTo(boolean arg);

}
```

Comment: i tried what you suggested but i got this as a result `Interface abstract methods cannot have body`

Comment: indeed, interfaces do not have a body.  see WJS' answer